# Как в медиазапросе отличить монитор с низким разрешением от смартфона?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Подключаю с помощью тега `<link>` разные файлы CSS в зависимости от разрешения, используя медиа-запросы:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1910px)" href="/common/bp_res1.css" type="text/css">
```

Вопрос в том, как в медиазапросе определить, что сайт просматривают с устройства с маленьким экраном?
Определение с помощью `handheld` больше не работает, если же проверять размер окна, современные смартфоны выдают большие цифры (в районе 1000 пикселей).
Соответственно, не получается отличить монитор с низким 
разрешением от смартфона. При этом запрещать масштабирование нельзя, т.е. нужно, чтобы на смартфоне помещалась вся страница, но было понятно, что это смартфон (в частности, чтобы увеличить шрифт ссылок).

Comment: По идее надо получить что-то типа dpi .. ?

Comment: Не понятно - зачем это нужно? Ведь можно вписать `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` и в стилях описывать как нужно.

Comment: Вроде справился, спасибо!